# Combining two arrays elements or distributing one arrays elements to another?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to distribute the elements of array ab[i] to posi[i] (absolute values + positive)

```
ints entered:- [1,2,3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,-9, 0(to quit)]
posi[i] = [1,2,3,4,5]
av[i] = [9,8,7,6] since I've reversed them
```

Then, the new array should be `[1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7,6]` or `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Here's what I've done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int sentinel=0;
const int arraysize=20;
int main()
{
    int numbers[arraysize];
    int neg[arraysize];
    int posi[arraysize];
    int ab[arraysize];
    int count=0;
    int negcount=0;
    int posicount=0;
    int absolutecount=0;
    int absolute;
    int num;

    cout << "Enter ints -0 to quit: ";
    cin >> num;
    while (num != sentinel && count < arraysize)
    {

        numbers[count] = num;
        cin >> num;
     }

    //   Negative
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    if ( numbers[i] < 0)
    {
        neg[negcount]=numbers[i];
        negcount++;
    }
    cout << "Absolute value: ";
    for (int i= negcount-1; i >= 0;i--)
    {
        absolute = neg[i]*-1;
        ab[i] =absolute;
        cout << ab[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    //   Negative

    for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
    if ( numbers[i] > 0)
    {
        posi[posicount] = numbers[i];
        posicount++;
    }
    cout << "Positive Number: ";
    for ( int i=0; i<posicount; i++)
        cout << posi[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `numbers[count] = num;` You don't increment count: `numbers[count++] = num;`

Comment: So which is the right answer?  Is it `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` or `[1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7,6]`?

Comment: doesn't matter as long as it is synced

Comment: @kamalilama Then if you really want a C++ answer, it takes 3 lines of code, not a bunch of `for` loops.

Comment: Essentially you want all negative values in the array to be converted to positive ?

Comment: I want absolute ab[i] number values distributed to the positive number values array posi[i] in general more like combining together cause later I have to separate them into two arrays of even nums and odd nums

Comment: @kamalilama Are you creating the `pos`, `neg` etc. arrays just as temporary arrays to solve the problem?  If so, you don't need them to rearrange the data in the way you described.  You can rearrange the data using the original array only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for the `neg`, `pos`, and `ab` arrays to solve the issue of rearranging the data in the form you described.

Since this is C++, let's use some STL algorithm functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4,5,-6,-7,-8,-9};

    // partition negatives from positive numbers
    auto iter = std::stable_partition(std::begin(numbers), 
                                      std::end(numbers), [](int n)
                                     { return n >= 0; });

    // reverse the negative numbers
    std::reverse(iter, std::end(numbers));

    // make the negative numbers positive
    std::for_each(iter, std::end(numbers), [](int& n){ n *= -1; });

    // output results
    for (auto& i : numbers)
      std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Functions used:

[std::stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition)

[std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

[std::for_each](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/UT3Oul)

Note that there is no need for auxiliary arrays to solve the problem.  The `numbers` array is rearranged and changed only.